# Is CEP what I need (system state and event replaying)

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing, esper

I'm looking for a CEP engine, but I' don't know if any engine meets my requirements.
My system has to process multiple streams of event data and generate complex events and this is exactly what almost any CEP engine perfectly fits (ESPER, Drools).

I store all raw events in database (it's not CEP part, but I do this) and use rules (or continious queries or something) to generate custom actions on complex events. But some of my rules are dependent on the events in the past.
For instance: I could have a sensor sending event everytime my spouse is coming or leaving home and if both my car and the car of my fancy woman are near the house, I get SMS 'Dangerous'.

The problem is that with restart of event processing service I lose all information on the state of the system (is my wife at home?) and to restore it I need to replay events for unknow period of time. The system state can depend not only on raw events, but on complex events as well.

The same problem arises when I need some report on complex events in the past. I have raw events data stored in database, and could generate these complex events replaying raw events, but I don't know for which exactly period I have to replay them.

At the same time it's clear that for the most rules it's possible to find automatically the number of events to be processed from the past (or period of time to load events to be processed) to restore system state.
If given action depends on presence of my wife at home, CEP system has to request last status change. If report on complex events is requested and complex event depends on average price within the previous period, all price change events for this period should be replayed. And so on...

If I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

The [RuleCore CEP Server](http://www.rulecore.com/) might solve your problems if I remember correctly. It does not lose state if you restart it and it contains a virtual logical clock so that you can replay events using any notion of time.

Comment: ... and it contains support for location in the rule language so things like 'alert when person X enters area A, B or C' is easy... It remembers state of things is calls Entities and that makes is remember where your wife is currently

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question is whether current CEP products offer joining historical data with live events, but if that's what you need, Esper allows you to pull data from JDBC sources (which connects your historical data with your live events) and reflect them in your EPL statements. I guess you already checked the Esper website, if not, you'll see that Esper has excellent documentation with lots of cookbook examples

But even if you model your historical events after your live events, that does not solve your problem with choosing the correct timeframe, and as you wrote, this timeframe is use case dependent.

Answer (score 0):

As previous people mentioned, I don't think your problem is really an engine problem, but more of a use case one. All engines I am familiar with, including Drools Fusion and Esper can join incoming events with historical data and/or state data queried on demand from an external source (like a database). It seems to me that what you need to do is persist state (or "timestamp check-points") when a relevant change happens and re-load the state on re-starts instead of replaying events for an unknown time frame.

Alternatively, if using Drools, you can inspect existing rules (kind of reflection on your rules/queries) to figure out which types of events your rules need and backtrack your event log until a point in time where all requirements are met and load/replay your events from there using the session clock.

Finally, you can use a cluster to reduce the restarts, but that does not solve the problem you describe.

Hope it helps.